# Gnu Cobol in Mac os 10.9

Tags: homebrew, cobol, gnucobol

I'm trying to install OpenCobolIDE on a Mac I get
It is veerryyy old, it runs Mac OS Mavericks
I ever used Windows, and I tried to install OpenCobolIDe, and the IDE itself works, but when I try to install Homebrew and running it says

```
MacBook-Pro-di-Giulio:~ giulio$ brew
ERROR: Your version of macOS (10.9.5) is too old to run Homebrew!

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _openat
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/current/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _openat
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/current/bin/ruby
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I need opencobol to run programs, and homebrew to install opencobol
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: According to https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1056 the only way is: ensure you use an old homebrew and ensure it is never updated + manually install the bottles.
If this works for you: fine, if not I suggest to move this question to the [GnuCOBOL discussion board](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/help/) as soon as you've setup GCC or clang (possibly via xcode) and can compile with it, allowing us to build every dependency needed - resulting in newest GnuCOBOL on that old system. [the final result will then be added here, possibly as community wiki]

Comment: I didn't understood what the link you gaveme mean, I don't think it's a dependencies problem, but maybye a version problem and maybye I need to download an older version

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest version of macOS?